# the google sign in popup doesn't last long or it says "the requested action is invalid"

Tags: javascript, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I have a firebase web app the google sign in popup doesn't work it doesn't last or give me a message (check the picture) is there a soution

```
//sign in with google
const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const signInWithGoogle = document.querySelector('#google-icon');
signInWithGoogle.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider).then((result) => {
 const user = result.user;
 const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
 const accessToken = credential.accessToken;})
 .catch((error) => {
   const errorCode = error.code;
   const errorMessage = error.message;
   const email = error.email;
   const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
 });
});
```

[image]

Comment: auth API is correct ? did you give the project a privileges' to use the google login ?

Comment: Did you ever fix the issue?

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem while playing around with firebase auth.
My problem was that **http://127.0.0.1:3000/** wasn't authorized.

[firebase authorized domains](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6O8tB.png)

After I switched to **http://localhost:3000/** everything worked fine.

Comment: I can't thank you for that, I wannna give you a Party !

Comment: I did that. But it doesn't work for me. Could there be another reason for the error?

Comment: Possibly you (or someone else) restricted the API key. Try going to https://cloud.google.com and find your Firebase project. Then, go to APIs & Services > Credentials > Key made my firebase > three dots > edit key > and for testing, enable "Identity toolkit" and all things beggining with "Fireabse". This is what happened to me. and it fixed the problem. For production, you probably want to restrict the key even further, by limiting what it can be used on, and what APIs it can access.

Comment: However, it should be noted, that if you were to restrict the API key, first create a test key and test it on a test app, with the requirements that your production app requires. Try each feature, and ensure it works. If not, figure out which APIs you might need to enable/disable. For most apps, you can just turn off the restrictions, and as long as you have adequate security rules in Fireabse, no one can get to your data.

Comment: Having the same issue, specifically in your answer "http://127.0.0.1:3000/ " was not authorized, we aren't able to add "http://127.0.0.1:3000/ " with the port number. Port number cant be included. 
Regardless, still getting "action is invalid" after adding local host to authorized domains

Answer (score 3):

I had the same error, but I found that you could solve it just by adding "browserPopupRedirectResolver" as a third parameter in the signInWithPopup() function

**Your code should be:**

```js
import { browserPopupRedirectResolver } from "firebase/auth";

//sign in with google
const googleProvider = new GoogleAuthProvider();
const signInWithGoogle = document.querySelector('#google-icon');
signInWithGoogle.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
signInWithPopup(auth, googleProvider, browserPopupRedirectResolver).then((result) => {
 const user = result.user;
 const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromResult(result);
 const accessToken = credential.accessToken;})
 .catch((error) => {
   const errorCode = error.code;
   const errorMessage = error.message;
   const email = error.email;
   const credential = GoogleAuthProvider.credentialFromError(error);
 });
});
```

It works for me, hope you do the same

Answer (score 0):

With the new version of firebase you have to add all of your domains to Firebase Installations API.
Go to google cloud console.

1. API & Service section;
2. Firebase Installations API.
3. Credentials
4. Browser key (by firebase)
5. Add all domains that you want to reach your app.

Thanks !